# Is it possible to get GridSpec from Figure before adding Axes?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Consider the following code

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
grid = fig.add_gridspec(2,2)
```

We have that `grid` is a `GridSpec` instance.

Consider now the following code

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
fig.add_gridspec(2,2)
```

The only way to retrieve the `GridSpec` associated to `fig` that I found is either to use the first code snippet I posted or to add a `Subplot` first and then get the `GridSpec` from such a  `Subplot`:

```
axes = fig.add_subplot(grid[0])
grid = axes.get_gridspec()
```

But what if I want to get the `GridSpec` from `fig` directly and before adding any `Subplot`?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code defining the `add_gridspec` method:

```
    def add_gridspec(self, nrows=1, ncols=1, **kwargs):
        """
        ...
        """
        _ = kwargs.pop('figure', None)  # pop in case user has added this...
        gs = GridSpec(nrows=nrows, ncols=ncols, figure=self, **kwargs)
        self._gridspecs.append(gs)
        return gs
```

`Figure._gridspecs` is a list of gridspecs, e.g.,

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
... fig = plt.figure()
... fig.add_gridspec(2, 2)
... fig.add_gridspec(4, 4)
... fig._gridspecs
[GridSpec(2, 2), GridSpec(4, 4)]
>>>
```